# Definition of "Created At and Updated At" database attributes

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Im trying to figure out what the best way to define the Created At and Updated At fields in a Custom Magento database table is.

i would like the following functionality.

when a new row is inserted, the "Created At" attribute is automatically given a value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and the "Updated at" attribute is assigned NULL.

when a row is updated the "Created At" attribute is not changed and that the "Updated at" attribute is automatically updated to the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

So far I have :

```
CREATE TABLE `instances` (
`instance_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY  (`instance_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

which fails with : #1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause

I am trying to make heads and tails of this article [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp-initialization.html) but am only growing more confused. clarification here will be greatly appreciated!

thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ther is only 1 entry with DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. This is MySql thing.
2. Magento sets those fields in other way: by setting those attributes before save on several models. So look those:

```
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Time_Updated
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Time_Created
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute
```

Answer (score 2):

This limitation has been removed in a recent release of MySQL (5.6.5) [see other stackoverflow thread with answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17498167/296812)