# MySQL date column in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm building registration form for my teacher's website.
I have created database called "students" with various rows like "name, surname etc."
Now I would like to add a column named "date_submitted" which will automatically insert current date and time to the row when data is submitted.

For example a student submits his data, the data is inserted into the table and mysql automatically fills the date and time when this insertion occured.

I tried @MLBDG answer from this question [MySQL date column auto fill with current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226571/mysql-date-column-auto-fill-with-current-date) but it doesn't work.

This is the way I do it:
[image]
Query:

```
ALTER TABLE `students` ADD `date_submitted` TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER ;
```

The error I'm receiving:

*#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1*

Server version: 5.5.34 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: You could always try [THE ? Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html) Its all in there somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `AFTER` keyword at the end of your query:

```
ALTER TABLE `students` ADD `date_submitted` TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Syntax: [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)

If using the `AFTER` keyword in your `ALTER TABLE` query, it must be followed by the name of a field in the table you are modifying.

Answer (score 0):

Remove After Keyword at the end of your query

`ALTER TABLE`students`ADD`date_submitted`TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`