# How write automaticaly the name of the day in the name of a table?

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I would like to know how to automatically write the name of the current  day in the table name when i execute a request like :

from qgpltemp.**monday**  (if i run on monday)

from qgpltemp.**tuesday** (if i run on tuesday)

etc...

(the table is already created with the good name before executing the request)

I have Tried :

```
select DAYNAME(CURRENT_DATE)as day,cast (row1 as integer) from qgpltemp.:day
```

and some other things , but i often get the error :

```
Error: [SQL0104] Elément syntaxique : n'est pas correct. Eléments possibles : <IDENTIFIER>.
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: -104
```

The command `DAYNAME(CURRENT_DATE)as day` works fine, i only get the name of the day if i manually write **.monday** etc...

Comment: Why are you embedding *data* in the *metadata* of the system, rather than keeping it as queryable data?

Comment: possibly dublicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226571/mysql-date-column-auto-fill-with-current-date

Comment: I don't know if i will ask correctly your question , but i try to make a request in a way that the user will not re-write each day the request for changing the name of the table because after i will integrate that request in a soft and a user will just execute a run for obtain the result.

Comment: But this would be *trivial* to solve if you just had a single table and an additional *column* containing the day - you'd just include the day as a condition in your `WHERE` clause. By embedding the day data in your table names, you're making this (and likely every other query) significantly more complex.

Comment: I will change my table as u write, it's probably the best option, thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this could be what you're looking for

```
declare @day varchar(max)
select @day = datename(dw,getdate())

declare @sqlCommand varchar(max)
Select @sqlCommand = 'Select * from qgpltemp.' + @day

exec(@sqlCommand)
```

if you insert that in your script it will execute the command to select all from a table called the current day.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i will change the configuration of my table, however i will keep in mind your solution

Comment: I was providing the literal answer to your problem. 'Damien_The_Unbeliever ' provided a useful comment under your question, I think changing your table design if possible is the best approach also! good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Create an alias for the current day.  Then your procedures can just point to the alias.

```
CREATE or replace ALIAS Qgpltemp.today FOR QGPLTEMP.MONDAY ;

select * from qqgpltemp.today;
```