# MySQL ERROR 1064 (42000) (Also when I add backticks everywhere)

Tags: mysql

I get MySQL ERROR 1064 (42000) when I try to run this code :

```
create table articles (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`title` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`description` VARCHAR(255),
`created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME, `users_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE
CASCADE);
```

Then I get this error : "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURRENT_TIME, `users_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`users' at line 1".
I already tried with and without backticks everywhere but it still gave me the same error... I think it probably has to do with the foreign key because I created a user table before without a foreign key and it worked.

Comment: The default for created_at (datetime) is not allowed. You can either use a timestamp or a trigger, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400147/mysql-current-timestamp-as-default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think CURRENT_TIME is valid for MySQL - it should be CURRENT_TIMESTAMP so try below which works for me (bar the foreign key as I do not have the users table):

```
create table articles (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`title` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`description` VARCHAR(255),
`created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `users_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE
CASCADE);
```

Comment: CURRENT_TIME is not the same as CURRET_TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 0):

'use the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

https://dbfiddle.uk/K_cGe49R

Voting to close as typo..

Comment: If you rule every question as a typo because "they didn't write the correct code" then every question on this site is a typo. I would reserve typos for cases where someone _meant_ to write the correct code, but they accidentally hit a key they didn't intend. That's what a typo is.

Comment: @Bill Karwin I agree. most of the questions which hit here(mysql in particular) are RTFMs not really programing issues at all . it is a pity there isn't an applicable close code.

Comment: I don't think those questions should be closed. Not everyone has the time to read a 4,000 page reference manual. If you don't want to answer it, you don't have to.