# Unable to create 2 timestamp columns in 1 MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, time

My sql query looks like this

```
ALTER TABLE `exercises`
ADD COLUMN `creation_dt`  timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER `lesson_id`,
ADD COLUMN `modification_dt`  timestamp NULL DEFAULT '' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER `creation_dt`;
```

But getting error message

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489548/why-there-can-be-only-one-timestamp-column-with-current-timestamp-in-default-cla).

Comment: Did you solve this yet? Trigger should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the screenshot, this is error code [`1293`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_too_much_auto_timestamp_cols). [The reason for this error seems to be some implementation details in MySQL.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4490006/95033)

You could get around it by using a column of type `DATETIME` but this does not allow setting the current time as `default` value. However, you can solve this in your application code or by using a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html). I used a sample table (called `datetimetest`) and added the trigger like this:

Database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `datetimetest` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `created` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_SetCreated
  BEFORE INSERT ON datetimetest
  FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.created = UTC_TIMESTAMP();
```

You can do the same for the `modified` field using a trigger `BEFORE UPDATE` or keep your solution as you now only have one `TIMESTAMP` column that gets set to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` `ON UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

you can't have multiple timestamp in a table, Still if you want to insert two dates/datetime in your table go for one timestamp and another datetime type.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple columns with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in one table. If you really need to you can use a 'before insert' trigger to emulate them'.