# I can't insert proper timestamp to mysql database and I don't know why

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a table in my database that contains three fields:

```
id  |  start_time  |  modification_time
```

When I look at it in phpmyadmin, I see that:

- id is primary key, auto increment, int
- start_time has type timestamp, default value is NULL
- modification_time is also timestamp, has attribute on update Current_timestamp and the default value is current_timestamp.

When I do simple insert query in which I provide only start_time (because as I assume two more values are filled automatically), I have the value 0000-00-00 00:00:00 there. I think that's because there's null value as default for that field. However, I cannot change it, because when I try, I get the error:

```
#1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause
```

How can I fix that then?

The result of the query:
show create table table_name
is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `Table` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `start_time` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `modification_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
        DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: please post `show create table table_name` results here

Comment: you have answers @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489548/why-there-can-be-only-one-timestamp-column-with-current-timestamp-in-default-cla and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-5.html

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory...

Comment: I added the result of the query shown by Ravinder... I've read also the suggested links, but I'm still confused about that - could you give me some hint how could I even start fixing that problem?