# timestamp error in mysql while installing magento

Tags: mysql, magento-1.9, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.5

i am having an error in mysql while installing magento in server`
currently mysql version is 5.5

```html
a:5:{i:0;s:295:"Error in file: "/home/jobixcoindia/public_html/app/code/local/Ced/CsMarketplace/sql/csmarketplace_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.0.3-0.0.4.php" - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1293 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause";i:1;s:1012:"#0 /home/jobixcoindia/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /home/jobixcoindia/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '0.0.3', '0.0.28')
#2 /home/jobixcoindia/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('0.0.3', '0.0.28')
#3 /home/jobixcoindia/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /home/jobixcoindia/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /home/jobixcoindia/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /home/jobixcoindia/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/jobixcoindia/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

`

Comment: The version of Magento you are trying to install requires MySQL-5.6.5 at least. This question is an exact dupe of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489548/why-there-can-be-only-one-timestamp-column-with-current-timestamp-in-default-cla?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Magento Column for date should be TYPE of DATETIME, like default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP