# How to insert two datetime fields with same server time in mysql?

Tags: mysql, node-mysql

I have a table with two fields insert_time and update_time.
The type of `insert_time` is `varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''` while the type of `update_time` is `timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

```
insert into tableName(inser_time,update_time) values('2017-02-17 20:30:38')
```

will make the `update_time` lose its meanings.

So how to make the two fields have a same server time when inserted if not update the Mysql version?

Comment: Why are you storing date information as `varchar`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen for my mysql version.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17498167/1468517

Comment: Use `NOW()` in the insert statement. Or use a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set both fields to the same value ?

```
insert into tableName(inser_time,update_time) 
values('2017-02-17 20:30:38','2017-02-17 20:30:38')
```

EDIT to use current time

```
insert into tableName(inser_time,update_time) 
values(now(), now())
```

EDIT 2 From mysql manual at: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

> Functions that return the current date or time each are evaluated only
>   once per query at the start of query execution. This means that
>   multiple references to a function such as NOW() within a single query
>   always produce the same result.

Comment: I want the save value with server date time

Comment: will  the two `now()` have exact the same value ? I mean, it  may take time for mysql to execute two functions.

Comment: I believe that now will be evaluated once by the database engine and so, yes both should have the same value