# MariaDB/MySql: Setting CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on CREATE and changing noting on UPDATE

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have not used MySQL in a few years and when I created a new table it did something I was not expecting. I am using **MariaDB v5.5.60-MariaDB**

I need to create a table that has both a `created` column and an `updated` column.

I need the `created` column to only be set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP when the row is created and then never change unless I change it explicitly.

I need the `updated` column to be set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP both when the row is created and when the row is changed.

If I do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE user_prefs (
  id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
  user VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  provider VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  pref VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  jsondata LONGTEXT,
  created timestamp NOT NULL,
  modified timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE INDEX id_UNIQUE (id ASC));
```

Then the `created` column is set to:
**DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**

and the `modified` column is set to:
**DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'**

If I try this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_prefs (
  id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
  user VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  provider VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  pref VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  jsondata LONGTEXT,
  created timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  modified timestamp NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE INDEX id_UNIQUE (id ASC));
```

Then I get the error **Error Code: 1293. Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause
**

So is there a way to automate setting both `created` and `modified` on creation of a row and then to change `modified` every time the row is change?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17498167/4003419). Upgrade?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A table might have automatic initialization of date in only one column in old versions of MySQL. But its behavior fixed in [version 5.6.5.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-5.html)
It means you have several ways to avoid this error:

**1.You can upgrade your MySQL to the latest version;**

---

*Advantages:*

- native clear implementation of modification dates management in a database side
- there aren't excess triggers

*Вrawback:*

- if the current version of MySQL is used in exists projects then upgrading might make some problems.

---

**2.You can create triggers for updating and the creation of a record, as @Simonare said**

*Advantages:*

- implementation of modification dates management in a database side

*Вrawback:*

- there are many excess triggers. You'll create two triggers for each table. It means you'll create N*2 triggers for N tables.

---

**3.You can set default value of `created` column to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` and set default value of `updated` column to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`.** In this case date of updating will be generated automatically. Also if you write `null` to `created` column MySQL will generate current date automatically and set it to the column. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE example_table (
  created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

If you execute the following query:

```
INSERT INTO example_table (created) VALUES (null);
```

`created` column will have current date value. MySQL will fill it automatically.

*Advantages:*

- there aren't excess triggers

*Вrawback:*

- implementation of modification dates management in a database side and client application side

---

**4.You can use automatic initialization of date in `updated` column and use trigger to fill `created` column**. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE example_table (
  created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER example_table_set_created_date
BEFORE INSERT
   ON example_table FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET NEW.created = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
END; //    
DELIMITER;
```

*Advantages:*

- implementation of modification dates management in a database side

*Вrawback:*

- there are many excess triggers. You'll create N triggers for N tables.

Answer (score 2):

you can create trigger for this

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER user_prefs_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT
   ON user_prefs FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
   SET NEW.updated = new.created;
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

then another trigger for update

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER user_prefs_before_update
BEFORE UPDATE
   ON user_prefs FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
   SET NEW.updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  users (
  created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  modified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is a reference of the documentation behind this [11.2.5 Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)