# Trigger for inserting/updating current date running into error MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'd like to create an `update/insert` trigger for the current date (to save a timestamp when it got modified last). So, since I read that you cannot define an `update/insert` trigger, but I need to define two triggers for this, I started off with an `insert`-trigger.

I do have the following code:

```
drop table if exists test;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
    id int,
    mydate datetime not null default now(),
    ts datetime
);
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_test_timestamp;
CREATE TRIGGER `update_test_timestamp` 
AFTER INSERT ON `test` 
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN  
    UPDATE `test` SET `ts` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE `id` = NEW.id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (1);
```

Basically, I want to save a timestamp on creation and an "lastupdate"-timestamp (`ts`). Sadly he error:

> Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'test' in stored function/trigger
>   because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored
>   function/trigger.

What did I do wrong? When I try to modify it to an `update`-trigger (instead of `insert`) I get the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `UPDATE` clause. You can just use

`SET NEW.`ts`= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();`

Ideally if you would like to have automatic timestamps for each updates, you could modify your table like this.

```
ALTER TABLE `test` 
CHANGE COLUMN `ts` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

which converts your `ts` field to a timestamp field and saves the timestamp whenever you update any field in your table.

Comment: Thanks for that! That's a solution for MySQL 5.6.5 and later, but if I am running prior versions, [I cannot define multiple columns with default/on update statements when it comes to timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489548/why-there-can-be-only-one-timestamp-column-with-current-timestamp-in-default-cla) - which is why i am actually having this trigger problem. Do you also have a solution for that?

Comment: what's wrong with `SET NEW.ts= now();` in your trigger. that should solve your update issue.

Comment: I am dumb, it indeed worked out, I just had to change the "AFTER" to "BEFORE" in my trigger and apply the changes you suggested. Thanks!